# How to dynamically calculate week of supply based on ending balance and future forecast?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have the following 2 tables/dataframes:

```
data1 = {
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'B'],
    'category': [1, 2, 2],
    'start_balance': [300, 3000, 80]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1
```

```
data2 = {
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'category': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'week': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'forecast': [82, 273, 232, 176, 142, 972, 1041, 503, 510, 566, 19, 15, 15, 13, 14],
    'end_balance': [400, 520, 288, 395, 253, 188, -853, -1356, -1866, -2432, 61, 40, 80, 67, 53]
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2
```

`df1` represents list of groups/categories (key) and a starting balance.

`df2` shows what is the forecast and ending balance for each of the key. Note that ending balance is a result of multiple factors not included in here as they are not relevant to the task.

I need to accomplish:

1. Add a column `"wks_of_supply"` to `df1` that calculates how many weeks of supply are left based on `"start_balance"` in `df1` and `"forecast"` for same key in `df2`. Starting with week 1 need to determine how many weeks can be covered in full and then prorate the last week. If balance coveres all the way to the end of the forecast would result in inf (note need to still be a float).

Here is the expected result:

| group | category | start_balance | wks_of_supply |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 300 | 1.798534799 |
| A | 2 | 3000 | 3.949019608 |
| B | 2 | 80 | inf |

2. Apply similar logic to `df2` to add `"wks_of_supply"` column. Note that forecast would start with week 2 as week 1 forecast is already used for `"start_balance"` `"wks_of_supply"` in `df1`. Because of this last week will alway be `NaN`. Also need to allow for negative and `-inf` `"wks_of_supply"`.

Here is the expected result:

| group | category | week | forecast | end_balance | wks_of_supply |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 82 | 400 | 1.547413793 |
| A | 1 | 2 | 273 | 520 | 2.788732394 |
| A | 1 | 3 | 232 | 288 | 1.788732394 |
| A | 1 | 4 | 176 | 395 | inf |
| A | 1 | 5 | 142 | 253 | NaN |
| A | 2 | 1 | 972 | 188 | 0.180595581 |
| A | 2 | 2 | 1041 | -853 | -1.68627451 |
| A | 2 | 3 | 503 | -1356 | -inf |
| A | 2 | 4 | 510 | -1866 | -inf |
| A | 2 | 5 | 566 | -2432 | NaN |
| B | 2 | 1 | 19 | 61 | inf |
| B | 2 | 2 | 15 | 40 | 2.857142857 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 15 | 80 | inf |
| B | 2 | 4 | 13 | 67 | inf |
| B | 2 | 5 | 14 | 53 | NaN |

Will need to run this on ~2 million rows dataset so need something that will run as fast as possible though will be probably hard to vectorize.

Tried creating a list of keys and then run a `for` loop to find the week where balance would go negative. Then read the results into a df and calculate the partial week fraction. This have worked only to solve #1 and was very slow.

Comment: How is 1.776556777 calculated? For the first weeks-of-supply figure, I get (300 - 82)/273 + 1 = 1.798534 .

Comment: Your calculation is correct.  Must have made a mistake in my Exel.  Will correct and edit original question when back at my PC. Thanks so much!

Comment: then... why is it not the same as what you've showed?

Comment: Sorry will correct soon, just checked the second line and that one looks ok.  You are right in your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with vectorised code, though in one place I found I needed to drop out of Pandas to Numpy for indexing:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'group':         ( 'A',  'A', 'B'),
    'category':      (  1,    2,   2),
    'start_balance': (300, 3000,  80),
}).set_index(['group', 'category'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
    'category': (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    'week': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'forecast': (82, 273, 232, 176, 142, 972, 1041, 503, 510, 566, 19, 15, 15, 13, 14),
    'end_balance': (400, 520, 288, 395, 253, 188, -853, -1356, -1866, -2432, 61, 40, 80, 67, 53),
}).set_index(['group', 'category', 'week'])

declining_balance = (
    df1['start_balance'] -
    df2['forecast'].groupby(['group', 'category']).cumsum()
).unstack('week').iloc[:, ::-1]

exhausted_idx = declining_balance.apply(pd.Series.searchsorted, axis=1, value=0)
is_exhausted = declining_balance.iloc[:, 0] <= 0
whole_weeks = declining_balance.shape[1] - exhausted_idx
whole_weeks[~is_exhausted] = np.inf
y_idx = np.arange(declining_balance.shape[0])[is_exhausted]

numerator = declining_balance.values[
    y_idx,
    exhausted_idx[is_exhausted],
]
denominator = df2.forecast.unstack('week').values[
    y_idx,
    (declining_balance.shape[1] - exhausted_idx)[is_exhausted],
]

weeks_of_supply = whole_weeks.copy()
weeks_of_supply[is_exhausted] += numerator/denominator
print(weeks_of_supply)
```

```
group  category
A      1           1.798535
       2           3.949020
B      2                inf
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  Basically move data from pandas to numpy then solve.
I don't know enough pandas to get the numpy results into the pandas dataframes.  Perhaps someone else does?

The approach is to use `np.interp` to lookup the week number (as a non integer float) where the cumulative supply == cumulative forecast.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'B'],
    'category': [1, 2, 2],
    'start_balance': [300, 3000, 80]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1

data2 = {
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'category': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'week': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'forecast': [82, 273, 232, 176, 142, 972, 1041, 503, 510, 566, 19, 15, 15, 13, 14],
    'end_balance': [400, 520, 288, 395, 253, 188, -853, -1356, -1866, -2432, 61, 40, 80, 67, 53]
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Data to 2D numpy arrays

fcast = np.array( df2.pivot_table( values = 'forecast', 
        index = ['group', 'category'], columns = 'week'), np.float )
end_bal = np.array( df2.pivot_table( values = 'end_balance', 
    index = ['group', 'category'], columns = 'week'), np.float )

# Week numbers as np array
week_no = np.arange( 1., fcast.shape[1] + 1 )


fcast_cum = fcast.cumsum( axis = 1 )  # Cumulative forecast
cum_supply = fcast_cum + end_bal  # What's been supplied is issued or in stock

supply_weeks = np.zeros_like( fcast )
for ix in range( fcast.shape[0] ):
    # Interpolate when the cumulative supply == cumulative forecast
    # np.interp needs 1d arrays for it's x and y parameters
    supply_weeks[ ix ] = np.interp( cum_supply[ix], fcast_cum[ix],
                                    week_no, right = np.inf ) - week_no

# Do the same for the start balances
start_bal = np.array(df1['start_balance']) 
start_weeks = np.zeros( start_bal.shape[0] )
for ix in range( fcast.shape[0] ):
    start_weeks[ ix ] = np.interp( start_bal[ix], fcast_cum[ix], 
                                   week_no, right = np.inf )


fcast                                                                                                     
# array([[  82.,  273.,  232.,  176.,  142.],
#        [ 972., 1041.,  503.,  510.,  566.],
#        [  19.,   15.,   15.,   13.,   14.]])

end_bal                                                                                                   
# array([[  400.,   520.,   288.,   395.,   253.],
#        [  188.,  -853., -1356., -1866., -2432.],
#        [   61.,    40.,    80.,    67.,    53.]])

supply_weeks    
# array([[ 1.54741379,  2.78873239,  1.78873239,         inf,         inf],
#        [ 0.18059558, -0.81940442, -1.81940442, -2.81940442, -3.81940442],
#        [        inf,  2.85714286,         inf,         inf,         inf]])

start_weeks                                                                                               
# array([1.7985348 , 3.94901961,        inf])
```

Where the stock is negative the cumulative supply is before the week it occurs in.  This means the calculation should look backwards not forwards.  It's logically inconsistent to issue more items from stock than are already there.